# Terraform - Using merge function makes the argument not excepted

Tags: terraform

#### Terraform Version

```
Terraform v0.12.18
+ provider.aws v2.42.0
+ provider.grafana v1.5.0
+ provider.helm v0.10.4
+ provider.kubernetes v1.10.0
+ provider.local v1.4.0
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.ovh v0.5.0
+ provider.random v2.2.1
+ provider.template v2.1.2
+ provider.vault v2.7.0
```

#### Terraform Configuration Files

```
# mymodule/service.k8s.tf
resource "kubernetes_service" "wordpress" {
  metadata {
    labels = merge(var.deployment_config.labels, {
      app = "myname
      engine = "wordpress"
      tier = "frontend"
    })  
  }
  ...
}
```

```
# mymodule/variables.tf
variable "deployment_config" {
  description = "The deployment configuration."
  type = object({
    labels = map(string)
  })
}
```

```
# modules.tf
module "my-module" {
  source = "./mymodule"
  deployment_config = {
    labels = {
      environment = "production"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Error

```
An argument named "labels" is not expected here.
```

#### Expected Behavior

The metadata.labels argument of the resource "kubernetes_service" (and other kubernetes resources) attempt to receive a map(). This should simply create the resource with theses labels (of both maps):

```
labels = {
  app = "myname"
  engine = "wordpress"
  tier = "frontend"
  environment = "production"
}
```

#### Actual Behavior

Without the use of the `merge()` function by simply putting a single map is working.
But when the `merge()` function is used Terraform say that the argument is not excepted.

#### Steps to Reproduce

Have a module with an argument of type `map(string)` (in this case `kubernetes_service` with the argument `metadata.labels`) which merge a variable of type `map(string)` with an other one `map(string)`.
Pass to this module the variable of type `map(string)`.

Then, `terraform apply`

## Question

Why using `merge()` function makes the argument **not excepted** ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Could you update your question to include the full error message output, including the code snippet and any hints Terraform gave about the values of variables?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in `mymodule/service.k8s.tf`, there is a missing end quotation for the map key `app`'s value. When I tried to run a `terraform apply` with the missing end quotation, I received a `Error: Invalid multi-line string`. Perhaps that was the issue you received ?

This seems to work for me.

```sh
$ tree
.
├── main.tf
└── mymodule
    └── main.tf

1 directory, 2 files
```

```
$ cat main.tf
module "mymodule" {
  source = "./mymodule"

  deployment_config = {
    labels = {
      environment = "production"
    }
  }
}

output "mymodule" {
  value = module.mymodule
}
```

```
$ cat mymodule/main.tf 
variable "deployment_config" {
  description = "The deployment configuration."
  type = object({
    labels = map(string)
  })
}

locals {
  labels = merge(var.deployment_config.labels, {
    app    = "myname"
    engine = "wordpress"
    tier   = "frontend"
  })
}

output "deployment_config" {
  value = local.labels
}
```

```sh
$ ls
main.tf  mymodule/

$ terraform version
Terraform v0.12.18

$ terraform apply  

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

mymodule = {
  "deployment_config" = {
    "app" = "myname"
    "engine" = "wordpress"
    "environment" = "production"
    "tier" = "frontend"
  }
}
```